# how to export data from table and export into another table as a checkpoint in pgsql procedure

Tags: sql, database, postgresql, plpgsql, npgsql

i have table name transactions and i want a procedure to import transactions into transactions_checkpoint how to that ?

Answer (score 0):

create a container with an date column for history:

```
CREATE TABLE transactions_checkpoint (like transactions including all);
ALTER TABLE transactions_checkpoint ADD COLUMN checkpoint_date date;
```

then in your function

```
INSERT INTO transactions_checkpoint 
  SELECT *,now() as checkpoint_date FROM transactions;
```